# Center an image make me crazy

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm using wordpress and i would like to center an image of the top of my post.
I tried many way but nothing work.
So here is the code :

```
<div class="entry-thumb">
            <img width="183" height="260" src="http://localhost/bdtresor/wp-content/uploads/gmb1_mister.president.2.JPG" class="attachment-newsanchor-large-thumb size-newsanchor-large-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Image du post 222">
</div>
```

the css

```
.entry-thumb {
    max-width: 1000px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
}

.entry-thumb {
  border : 1px solid black ; 
  }

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I don't know how to do.When i pit a margin-left : 50px , it works but it's not centered , but if i put margin-left : auto , nothing happened...
Thank you for you're help

Comment: Yep, I was about to say "calm down with the language".

Answer (score 1):

Make the image `display:block` so that the margin centering works.

```css
.entry-thumb {
    max-width: 1000px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
}

.entry-thumb {
  border : 1px solid black ; 
  }

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-thumb">
            <img width="183" height="260" src="http://lorempixel.com/183/260" class="attachment-newsanchor-large-thumb size-newsanchor-large-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Image du post 222">
</div>
```

---

Keep in mind though that the `max-width` will conflict with the image dimensions since they are defined on the image. (*you should remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the `img` tag*)